# Can you instantiate another class within the constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, initialization

Can you instantiate another class within the constructor? If not then why?

```
public class Class1() {}

public class Class2() {

    public Class2() {

    Class1 c1 = new Class1();

    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is... yes... Next question?

Comment: Well, did you try? And if not, why not?

Comment: Wouldn´t it have been far easier and faster to just try it out? Is there a **specific** problem with that code?

Comment: I cannot use c1 anywhere in the code. It does not appear that the constructor actually initiated the Class1.

Comment: Because c1 is a method variable in your case

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but let me clarify, as you appear to be a beginner (welcome aboard, by the way): you instantiate an ***object*** of `Class1`. A class cannot be instantiated. In your example, that object is a local variable which will be destroyed once all the code inside the constructor is executed. Practically, this means you cannot use `c1` anywhere but inside the constructor. You can make it a *member* (a **field**, specifically) of `Class2` by declaring it in the class body and bound its existence to that of an object of `Class2`, for example:

```
public class Class1() { }

public class Class2() 
{
    Class1 c1;

    public Class2() 
    {
       c1 = new Class1();
    }
}
```

This allows for `c1` to be used anywhere inside the class.

Comment: Yes! This was my problem! I was trying to use c1 outside of the constructor which did not work. I know it's a silly example but I could not figure out why it should not work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I understand your concern, but as the OP seems to be a beginner, I'd rather be kind and nice.

Comment: @StackLloyd Because this question shows a complete lack of effort by the poster, and isn't even the problem they were trying to solve. The proper route to answering this should be for the poster to go and learn some basic C# skills.

Comment: I agree DavidG in learning some basics. Anyway this question is fine to answer, when OP includes all information into the question, which is currrently provided by comments. In particular the fact that OP wants to access `c1` outside the constructor seems a pretty specific issue and thus is fine posted here. However this should be provided within the **question itself**.

Comment: Or in other words: the question being **posted** is" Can I do this", which is easily answered by "yes". The **actual problem** is "How to use that instance in `Class2`", to which the answer is what you´ve written above.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Either this question is as posted which means it's a terrible post and should not be answered, or OP should have asked the real question in which case it's almost certainly a duplicate because it's about variable scope.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you definitely can instantiate a class inside a constructor method of another class. The problem that you are facing is variable scope, i.e. where it can and can't be used/accessed. You need to define the variable in the "area" where you want to use it, i.e. in your class, constructor, method, property, etc. Using the code in your original post, I will try to explain.

The class to be instantiated:

```
public class Class1()
{
}
```

The class doing the instantiation:

```
public class Class2()
{
     public Class2()
     {
          Class1 c1 = new Class1();
     }
}
```

You won't be able to use variable `c1` any where because it is defined in the constructor. You would only be able to use it in this constructor, because this is where it was defined.

If you want to be able to use it some place else in `Class2` then I would suggest you define it outside of the constructor as below. This way you can use it anywhere in `Class2`:

```
public class Class2()
{
     Class1 c1 = null;

     public Class2()
     {
          // You can instantiate it in the constructor
          c1 = new Class1();
     }
}
```

Or you can maybe use it in a method in `Class2` as such:

```
public class Class2()
{
     Class1 c1 = null;

     public void Method1()
     {
          // You can instantiate it in the method
          c1 = new Class1();
     }
}
```

Play around and see what works for you. I normally instantiate a class where I want to use it. For example, if I need `Class1` in a method then then this is the place where I will define and instantiate it:

```
public class Class2()
{
     public void Method1()
     {
          Class1 c1 = new Class1();
     }
}
```

I hope this helps.